# Show a custom message if terms and condition checkbox is not checked

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, onepage-checkout

I am using the one-step checkout and Paypal payment method. On clicking the PayPal button on the checkout page, I want to show a custom message if the terms and conditions checkbox is not checked to notify the customer to check the terms and conditions checkbox. How can I do this? I could not find the click event for the Paypal button.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link 
[How to add validation on checkbox , select option and text fields in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319267/how-to-add-validation-on-checkbox-select-option-and-text-fields-in-magento-2)

I hope it will solve your issue.
Thanks,
Vibhore